# Android WebView not reconnecting on network change

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, mobile

I'm currently developing an Android application using WebView, where the WebView should automatically reconnect when the network changes. Unfortunately, I'm facing challenges, and the WebView doesn't reconnect immediately after the network is back online.

The WebView cannot reconnect as expected after a network change. I have a NetworkChangeReceiver to detect changes and the reconnect logic is not triggered.

```
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private void startWebview() {

.....

     if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        shouldLoadWebView = true;
        mWebView.loadUrl(mainPageUrl);
    } else {
        showFallbackImage();
    }

    registerReceiver(new NetworkChangeReceiver(), new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

}

private void reconnect() {
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        shouldLoadWebView = true;
        mWebView.loadUrl(mainPageUrl);
    } else {
        showFallbackImage();
        shouldLoadWebView = false;
    }
}

private void showFallbackImage() {
    mWebView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loading);
}

public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (isNetworkAvailable() && shouldLoadWebView) {
            reconnect();
        } else {
            showFallbackImage();
            shouldLoadWebView = false;
        }
    }
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
        return capabilities != null &&
                (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) ||
                        capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) ||
                        capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET));
    }

    return false;
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <receiver
        android:exported="true"
        android:name=".MainActivity$NetworkChangeReceiver"
        tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Any help or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why should a webview reconnect? When? There is no permanent connection to a http(s) server . And the webview also does not know if wifi or mobile connection is used.

Comment: @blackapps I want to display a default image when internet is lost, instead of WebPage not available default message  and when internet is restored connect to webview again

Comment: `showFallbackImage();
        shouldLoadWebView = false;` U think you should set "true" there.

Comment: Anyhow i cannot follow your use of `shouldLoadWebView`. And you mean should load url?